# cannot set sidekiq queue to 'default' in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, autoscaling

This is what I have in my NoteWorker that is fired up with a rake task.

**NoteWorker.rb**

```
class NoteWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options queue: "note"
  sidekiq_options :failures => true

  def perform(model_id)
    #do something
  end
end
```

**note.rake**

```
namespace :notes do

  task :send_note => :environment do
    NoteWorker.perform_async(model.id)
  end
end
```

Everything works as is.  But I am trying to autoscale, which can't seem to autoscale multiple workers so I am trying to change all the queues to "default" as opposed to custom names.  But when I delete the `sidekiq_options queue: "note"` or change it to `sidekiq_options queue: "default"` it gives me this error:

```
"Scaling worker to 1"
rake aborted!
Expected(200) <=> Actual(404 Not Found)
 request => {:connect_timeout=>60, :headers=>{"Accept"=>"application/json", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip", "Authorization"=>"Basic Og==", "User-Agent"=>"heroku-rb/0.2.1", "X-Heroku-API-Version"=>"3", "X-Ruby-Version"=>"1.9.3", "X-Ruby-Platform"=>"x86_64-darwin10.8.0", "Host"=>"api.heroku.com:443", "Content-Length"=>0}, :instrumentor_name=>"excon", :mock=>false, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_limit=>4, :ssl_ca_file=>"/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/excon-0.13.4/data/cacert.pem", :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"api.heroku.com", :path=>"/apps//ps/scale", :port=>"443", :query=>{"type"=>"worker", "qty"=>1}, :scheme=>"https", :expects=>200, :method=>:post}
response => #<Excon::Response:0x00000104700aa8 @body="{\"id\":\"not_found\",\"error\":\"Not found\"}", @headers={"Cache-Control"=>"no-transform", "Content-Type"=>"application/json;charset=utf-8", "Date"=>"Wed, 31 Jul 2013 02:32:25 GMT", "Status"=>"404 Not Found", "Strict-Transport-Security"=>"max-age=31536000", "X-Cascade"=>"pass", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "X-Runtime"=>"0.00246243", "Content-Length"=>"38", "Connection"=>"keep-alive"}, @status=404>
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/excon-0.13.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:266:in `request_kernel'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/excon-0.13.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:97:in `request'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/heroku-api-0.2.1/lib/heroku/api.rb:60:in `request'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/heroku-api-0.2.1/lib/heroku/api/processes.rb:43:in `post_ps_scale'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/autoscaler-0.3.0/lib/autoscaler/heroku_scaler.rb:38:in `workers='
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/autoscaler-0.3.0/lib/autoscaler/sidekiq/client.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/sidekiq-2.8.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:111:in `block in invoke'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/sidekiq-2.8.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:114:in `call'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/sidekiq-2.8.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:114:in `invoke'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/sidekiq-2.8.0/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:112:in `process_single'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/sidekiq-2.8.0/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:40:in `push'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/sidekiq-2.8.0/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb:68:in `client_push'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/sidekiq-2.8.0/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb:38:in `perform_async'
/Users/user/rails_projects/notebook/lib/tasks/send_note.rake:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@notebook/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `each'
/Users/user/rails_projects/notebook/lib/tasks/send_note.rake:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => send_note:send_note
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: It may be a stupid suggestion, but did you restart sidekiq?

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire I get that msg when I run the rake task.  So I didn't even get to sidekiq yet.  Same issue if I change the queue to `default` rather than `note`

Comment: what's in `send_note.rake:24` ?

Comment: Why are you using rake to start sidekiq? If you have rbenv you should `bundle exec sidekiq (options)`, if you are not using rbenv you should `sidekiq (options)`

Comment: @MikeLi just noted the rake file on the original question.

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire I am using rake because I am using Heroku Scheduler to fire this up automatically everyday. I am also using autoscaler so I can run all this stuff without an actual person having to do this on a daily basis.

Comment: have you tried if the redis connection is working? `$ rails console >> REDIS.set("foo", "bar")`

Comment: @MikeLi yup it works.

Comment: can you print out the value of `model.id`?

Comment: @MikeLi, not sure what you mean.  Can you please clarify?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](https://github.com/JustinLove/autoscaler/issues/9).  JustinLove actually created an example file that he linked to in the chain.